# Segmented Button Control

Tags: ios, xcode, button, controls

Quick question: Does anyone know how I could create a segmented control that acts like a button. This kind of control can be found in apps like Yelp and Tweetbot.

[image: Tweetbot iOS segmented Button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pretty much hit the nail on the head by saying they act like buttons - you should implement each one as a separate `UIButton`. Although they seem joined they don't act like a `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: yes--make each one a button, then add logic in your control layer to be notified of when a button is tapped and turn off all other buttons, etc. If you want to make this a "widget", you could create a subclass of `UIView` that implements something like a segmented control with API for number of segments, icon for each segment, etc. You should not subclass `UISegmentedControl`

Comment: Thanks! I made a segmented control and put it on github here https://github.com/keirp/Glass-Segmented-Buttons-for-iOS-5.1-

Answer (score 0):

This is the control that I made and posted up on GitHub. https://github.com/keirp/Glass-Segmented-Buttons-for-iOS-5.1-